# Use Selenium cookies with postman generated POST snippet in Python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, python-requests, postman

I'm automating a task which requires me to POST some data along with cookies that update every few minutes. In order to get the updated cookies I use Selenium to refresh the page and then `driver.get_cookies()`.

I have a template for the POST request from Postman so all I have to do is replacing the old cookies with the new cookies from selenium.

The template:

```
import requests

url = "https://SECRET_URL"

payload={}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.68',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGjr6z5IrrtgTB6kb',
  'Cookie': 'resource_filter313=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22313%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter315=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22315%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter323=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22323%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter7=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%227%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; schedule_calendar_toggle=false; SimpleSAMLAuthToken=_b2d58eddf859a022f343f72695eb8297d32ea5f7b0; SimpleSAMLSessionID=4dcd7e60c53eb05ff6cda9edee39a505; tree311={"open_nodes":["13"],"selected_node":"14"}'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

**To clarify, all I need is to replace `'Cookies'` value in `headers` with the correctly formatted cookies from selenium.**
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want this:

```
  'Cookie': 'resource_filter313=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22313%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter315=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22315%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter323=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22323%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter7=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%227%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; schedule_calendar_toggle=false; SimpleSAMLAuthToken=_b2d58eddf859a022f343f72695eb8297d32ea5f7b0; SimpleSAMLSessionID=4dcd7e60c53eb05ff6cda9edee39a505; tree311={"open_nodes":["13"],"selected_node":"14"}'
```

To look pretty like this:

```
'Cookie':'resource_filter313={"ScheduleId":"313","ResourceIds":[],"ResourceTypeId":null,"MinCapacity":null,"ResourceAttributes":[],"ResourceTypeAttributes":[]};resource_filter315={"ScheduleId":"315","ResourceIds":[],"ResourceTypeId":"","MinCapacity":null,"ResourceAttributes":[],"ResourceTypeAttributes":[]};resource_filter323={"ScheduleId":"323","ResourceIds":[],"ResourceTypeId":null,"MinCapacity":null,"ResourceAttributes":[],"ResourceTypeAttributes":[]};resource_filter7={"ScheduleId":"7","ResourceIds":[],"ResourceTypeId":null,"MinCapacity":null,"ResourceAttributes":[],"ResourceTypeAttributes":[]};schedule_calendar_toggle=false;SimpleSAMLAuthToken=_b2d58eddf859a022f343f72695eb8297d32ea5f7b0;SimpleSAMLSessionID=4dcd7e60c53eb05ff6cda9edee39a505;tree311={"open_nodes":["13"],"selected_node":"14"}'
```

You need to decode it like this:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
bad_cookie = 'resource_filter313=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22313%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter315=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22315%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter323=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%22323%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; resource_filter7=%7B%22ScheduleId%22%3A%227%22%2C%22ResourceIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeId%22%3Anull%2C%22MinCapacity%22%3Anull%2C%22ResourceAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ResourceTypeAttributes%22%3A%5B%5D%7D; schedule_calendar_toggle=false; SimpleSAMLAuthToken=_b2d58eddf859a022f343f72695eb8297d32ea5f7b0; SimpleSAMLSessionID=4dcd7e60c53eb05ff6cda9edee39a505; tree311={"open_nodes":["13"],"selected_node":"14"}'

good_cookie = unquote(bad_cookie)

print(good_cookie)
```